# I want to take information from a form and put it into a table, and the right table as well

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

I am new to this with HTML, and I currently have a HTML project for school. The problem is that I need to take information from a form into a table(on the same page, and without a server so no reloading) and of course I do not know any PHP (this is what I am told is needed in order to make this work.)

This is the code for my form:

```
<form id="dispatch" name="dispatch" method="post" action="form.pxp">
    <select name="State" id="State">
        <option value=" Alabama"> Alabama</option>
        <option value=" Alaska"> Alaska</option>
        <option value=" Arizona"> Arizona</option>
        <option value=" Arkansas"> Arkansas</option>
        <option value=" California"> California</option>
        <option value=" Colorado"> Colorado</option>
        <option value=" Connecticut"> Connecticut</option>
        <option value=" Delaware"> Delaware</option>
        <option value=" Florida"> Florida</option>
        <option value=" Georgia"> Georgia</option>
        <option value=" Hawaii"> Hawaii</option>
        <option value=" Idaho"> Idaho</option>
        <option value=" Illinois"> Illinois</option>
        <option value=" Indiana"> Indiana</option>
        <option value=" Iowa"> Iowa</option>
        <option value=" Kansas"> Kansas</option>
        <option value=" Kentucky"> Kentucky</option>
        <option value=" Louisiana"> Louisiana</option>
        <option value=" Maine"> Maine</option>
        <option value=" Maryland"> Maryland</option>
        <option value=" Massachusetts"> Massachusetts</option>
        <option value=" Michigan"> Michigan</option>
        <option value=" Minnesota"> Minnesota</option>
        <option value=" Mississippi"> Mississippi</option>
        <option value=" Missouri"> Missouri</option>
        <option value=" Montana"> Montana</option>
        <option value=" Nebraska"> Nebraska</option>
        <option value=" Nevada"> Nevada</option>
        <option value=" New Hampshire"> New Hampshire</option>
        <option value=" New Jersey"> New Jersey</option>
        <option value=" New Mexico"> New Mexico</option>
        <option value=" New York"> New York</option>
        <option value=" North Carolina"> North Carolina</option>
        <option value="  North Dakota">  North Dakota</option>
        <option value=" Ohio"> Ohio</option>
        <option value=" Oklahoma"> Oklahoma</option>
        <option value=" Oregon"> Oregon</option>
        <option value=" Pennsylvania"> Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value=" Rhode Island"> Rhode Island</option>
        <option value=" South Carolina"> South Carolina</option>
        <option value=" South Dakota"> South Dakota</option>
        <option value=" Tennessee"> Tennessee</option>
        <option value=" Texas"> Texas</option>
        <option value=" Utah"> Utah</option>
        <option value=" Vermont"> Vermont</option>
        <option value=" Virginia"> Virginia</option>
        <option value=" Washington"> Washington</option>
        <option value=" West Virginia"> West Virginia</option>
        <option value=" Wisconsin"> Wisconsin</option>
        <option value=" Wyoming"> Wyoming</option>
    </select>
    Creature: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Report">
</form>
```

And here is the code for one of the tables (one for each state):

```
    <table cellspacing="0" id="california" class="table" for="path7">
    <tr>
        <th class="infoheader">California</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="th1">Creature</th>
        <th id="th2">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">Wolf</td>
        <td id="td2">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">Boar</td>
        <td id="td2">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">Elk</td>
        <td id="td2">7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I want to take the information from the form and put it into the right table(state).

Comment: If you're not allowed to use a server, then I imagine you're supposed to use Javascript instead of PHP :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I would suggest that you shorten the posted code to get an answer. That way answerers can see that you are not asking them to do your work for you and it also allows them to focus on the core of the solution. And this way you can learn more than you would otherwise :)